# How to set Monday as first day of the week on MaterialDatePickerComponent?

Tags: dart, angular-components, angular-dart

From API reference documentation, https://webdev.dartlang.org/api/angular_components/angular_components/MaterialDatepickerComponent-class, I can't find anyway to set Monday as first day of the week.

Is there a way to display calendar starting on Monday ?

Comment: Use `intl` package and call `Intl.defaultLocale = 'en_GB'; await initializeDateFormatting();`